# How to restore deleted facebook app?

Tags: facebook

One of my admin has deleted the application. Is there any way to restore it? How can I contact with facebook's developers?

Answer (score 24):

You can recover the deleted facebook app by requesting it by going in your developer account at https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/

If you are one of the admin of the app then you will see the deleted apps there. just click on restore and it will send an email to the administrator's contact email where they can restore it back!

Thanks

Comment: Any idea how long it took before you received the e-mail?

Comment: Never mind, the e-mail was sent fairly instant but it was incorrectly marked as spam.

Comment: @SolveSoul Were you able to restore the app successfully using this method?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim yes, I was. It's been more than a year since then, though.

Comment: @SolveSoul I am are facing the same situation here for a business-critical FB app. I have clicked the restore button but not sure when will I get an email and how long the whole restoring process takes. can you pls share how much time it took for you?

Comment: @Ajithkumar_sekar I'm sorry, it's been too long... I can't remember, but since I previously mentioned the mail was sent to my spam folder then I think it didn't take more than an hour to restore the whole Facebook app. The process might've been changed by now, though...

Comment: @SolveSoul thanks for your reply. The process is still the same. we got the app back in 5 hours. It was a nightmare in-between

Comment: @SolveSoul how long did it take to receive the email? I'm not getting it after more than 12 hours. Checked the spam box and tried with multiple apps and from another account. The emails seem to not be sent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but once the App is removed or deleted its permanent. You can't go back and recover it. Even when deleting the App same thing is also explicitly stated by Facebook

> If you proceed, this app will be deleted. This operation cannot be
>    undone.

Comment: Is there a way the recreate the app ? Is there a cooling off period that they require before you can recreate the app ?

Comment: Yes, you may recreate the app which will get a different set of App ID and App secret than your previous one. And as far as documentation goes there is no cooling off period, so I can safety say that you don't need to wait for one either.

Comment: Well. I guess Im filing a bug report. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Any chance for an update if filing a bug helped? Unfortunately one of our QA people did this as well on a deployed mobile app.

Comment: Sorry,but a deleted application can't be recovered

Comment: Is this answer verified with Facebook? @Anvesh, you seem very confident. :)

Comment: @DannyA I am confident. I have deleted quite a few apps in testing so I know the warning that pops up _This operation cannot be undone._

Comment: Link to the bug report?

Comment: the deleted app can be restored from ( did this personally while was finding how to)

https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/ in this link you'll see all deleted apps (recently), then ask for restoration request, you'll get an email to approve the restoration request, once you approve that it will be restored! Ty

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when my account was reported by someone. The Facebook app was temporarily deleted. Fortunately it all went fine when I restored the account from https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/  For this the email account set up with the app is required for receiving restore instructions.